# How do I make it so that my menu items are not overlapping in my mobile navigation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, uinavigationbar

I am making a mobile menu and my menu items are overlapping when I hover on top of them. I need it to be so that the menu items get pushed down when hovered on so that the text isn't on top of eachother.

HTML:

```
<nav> 

      <div class="logo">
      <a href="#"><img src="./images/Gardenliving-full-logo.png" alt="Logo"></a>
      </div>  

      <ul id="navMenu">

        <!-- OUTDOOR KITCHENS MENU -->
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Outdoor Kitchens</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Appliances</a>
            <ul class="appliances">
              <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">LYNX</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">COYOTE</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">CROWN VERITY</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">HESTAN</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">BIG GREEN EGG</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">ALFRESCO</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">FIRE MAGIC</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">PERLICK</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">EVO</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">FONTANA</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">WOLF</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">BLAZE</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">CABINETRY</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">ITEM 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">ITEM 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">ITEM 3</a></li>
          </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">COUNTERTOPS</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <!-- CABANA X MENU ITEM -->
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-item">CabanaX</a></li>

    <!-- PERGOLA X MENU -->
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-item">PergolaX</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">SMART PERGOLAS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SMART PERGOLA ACCESSORIES</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">WHY CHOOSE STRUXURE PERGOLAS</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>

      <!-- FIRE FEATURES MENU ITEM -->
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-item">Fire Features</a>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Hours of Operation</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>

      <!-- GALLERY MENU ITEMS -->
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-item">Gallery</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">OUTDOOR KITCHENS GALLERY</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CABANA X GALLERY</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">PERGOLA X GALLERY</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">OUTDOOR LIVING GALLERY</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>

      <!-- CONTACT MENU ITEM -->
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-item">Contact</a></li>

  <!-- CLOSING  -->
  </ul> 


  <div class="hamburger">
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
</div>

  </nav>
```

My CSS:

```
body{
  margin:0px
}

#header {
display: none;
}

img {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    max-height: 5vh;;
    max-width: 30vw;
}

nav {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
height: 10VH;
font-family: "futura-pt", sans-     serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
z-index: 100;
position:relative;
}

.logo {
flex: 1;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
width: auto;
height: auto;

}

.logo img 
{
  margin: 0 10%;
}

#navMenu {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  
  #navMenu li {
  margin: 0 1%;
  }
  
  ul#navMenu {
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  width:420px;
  list-style:none;
  position:relative;
  background: white;
  }
  
  ul#navMenu ul {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:100%;
  display:none;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px
  }
  
  ul#navMenu li {
  display:inline;
  float:left;
  position:relative
  }
  
  ul#navMenu a {
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:10px 5px;
  width:auto;
  color: black;
  float:left;
  text-align:left;
  background: white;
  /* border:1px solid #000000; */
  }
  
  ul#navMenu a:hover {
  /* background: #F5F5F5; */
  color:#00A7E1;
  }
  
  
  ul#navMenu ul ul {
  top:0;
  left:100%;
  }
  
  ul#navMenu li:hover ul ul {
  display:none;
  }
  
  ul#navMenu ul li:hover ul {
  display:block;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  }
  
  ul#navMenu li:hover ul {
  display:block;
  }
  
  ul#navMenu ul a {
  width:150px;
  }
  
  ul#navMenu ul li {
  display:block;
  margin:0px
  }
  
  
  /* CSS for hamburger menu icon */
  .hamburger {
    display: none;
}

.bar {
    display: block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #101010;
}


/* MEDIA QUERY FOR MOBILE */

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) { 
  #navMenu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 40rem;
    right: -100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    /* background-color: #fff; */
  
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 1s;
    box-shadow:
        0 10px 27px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

#navMenu.active {
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    background-color: aquamarine;
}

/* hamburger animations */
.hamburger {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

.hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
}

.hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
}



ul#navMenu ul ul {
  display: block;
  }

}
```

Javascript

```
const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
const navMenu = document.querySelector("#navMenu");

hamburger.addEventListener("click", mobileMenu);

function mobileMenu() {
    hamburger.classList.toggle("active");
    navMenu.classList.toggle("active");
}

const navLink = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link");

navLink.forEach(n => n.addEventListener("click", closeMenu));

function closeMenu() {
    hamburger.classList.remove("active");
    navMenu.classList.remove("active");
}
```

I have provided the code so that you may paste and may be able to answer my question. The text overlaps eachother when what I need it to do is push the other text down so it is readable.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the position:absolute from ul#navMenu ul,  It should work. You may need to do additional refactoring to do it fully responsive, but that's the way to do what you asked for.